# Nested condition for Azure Stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have 2 questions:

1. Does azure Stream analytics support nested conditions using the CASE statement ?
2. I see there are 2 formats of CASE expression mentioned here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/case-azure-stream-analytics . I found examples for searched CASE [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns). Can anyone give example for the Simple CASE expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Sample data :***

```
[{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake"
},
{
"id": "0002",
"type": "donut2",
"name": "Cake2"
]
```

> Does azure Stream analytics support nested conditions using the CASE
>   statement ?

Based on my test, it supports nested case conditions.

***SQL:***

```
select jsoninput.id as id, jsoninput.type as type ,
case when 
    ((case when  jsoninput.id = '0001' then '0' else '1' end) = '0' ) then '0'
else  '1' end as res
from jsoninput
```

***Output:***

[image]

> Can anyone give example for the Simple CASE expression?

***SQL:***

```
select jsoninput.id as id, jsoninput.type as type ,
case jsoninput.id when '0001' then 'true' else 'false' end as res 
from jsoninput
```

***Output:***

[image]